# How do I get XDG_CONFIG_HOME from a shell script / command line?

Tags: shell-script, environment-variables, directory-structure, xdg

Is `${XDG_CONFIG_HOME:-${HOME}/.config}` enough or there are more tricks to it?

Is there maybe some `xdg-user-dir CONFIG` or `xdg-settings` invocation that gives me where to expect programs' configs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`${XDG_CONFIG_HOME:-~/.config}` is exactly [how `xdg-user-dirs` does it](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xdg/xdg-user-dirs/blob/master/xdg-user-dir) (it's a shell script). It hasn't changed since 2008, so you can consider this to be stable.

Incidentally, you'd better not have whitespace or wildcard in the value of `XDG_CONFIG_HOME`. If `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` is unset, special characters in the home directory location are ok. Wildcards in the value of `XDG_xxx_DIR` also don't work, as do sequences of whitespace other than a single space.